# calculated Voltage explanation

Tags: circuit-analysis

The blue highlighted values are the answers, but can sombody explain how my teacher got 120v for the 4k resistor and 60v for the 2k resistor? the only one I could figure out is the right side where I showed 1 calcuation....

[image: circuit]

I was running through practice problems that my teacher provided for us to prep for the coming exam... but I cant understand how he came to those voltage values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a class assignment with no attempted solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If two resistors are in series then they have the same current. Also, the \$30mA\$ current source is in series with the \$2k\Omega\$ and \$4k\Omega\$ resistors. Therefore the \$4k\Omega\$ resistor has \$30mA\$. By Ohm's Law \$4k\Omega * 30mA = 120V\$. Likewise for the \$2k\Omega\$ resistor: \$2k\Omega * 30mA = 60V\$.